# How can I split this function into 2, so that it contains a main function?

Tags: python, function, parameters, arguments

I coded a user defined max function (even though it's included in the python default). This function works, but I cannot figure out how to split this into 2 functions! My main function needs to include the x and y input variables. I've been trying to figure out parameter/argument passing for hours now and still cannot figure out how to pass variables properly.

```
x=input("Enter integer value 1...")
y=input("Enter integer value 2...")

def max(x,y):
     if x > y:
         return x
     elif y > x:
         return y 


 print(max(x,y))
```

Comment: The function is so simple, I don't see any meaningful way to split it. What would the second function do?

Comment: BTW, what is it supposed to return when `x == y`?

Comment: I agree the function should be left as 1 block, but it is for an assignment. If x == y I have to make it display both numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just move the top-level code into the `main()` function.

```
def main():
    x=input("Enter integer value 1...")
    y=input("Enter integer value 2...")
    
    print(max(x, y))

if __name__ == "main":
    main()
```

Comment: I see now where I messed up. I was calling the print max function outside of the scope of the main function. Thank you for the valuable lesson Barmar, I appreciate it.